# Difference between maximals and minimum

Tags: order-theory

Given a partially ordered set $(U,\leq )$, its maximum is always a maximal, but none of its maximals may necessarily be a maximum, right?

In which cases is none of the maximals a maximum?

I understand the concept and I know that they are not the same, what I don't see is in which cases the maximals are not maximum. It's very clear with the order relationship of $|$ (divide a), but I don't understand it very well with the canonical relationship of the naturals ($\leq $).

Comment: Note that for the naturals with $\leq$ you actually define a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)

Comment: You can talk about maximum for chain only. For example, if the order relation is divisibility in $\mathbb N$, what would be the maximum of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ ?

Comment: @Surb , There is no maximum, but yes several maximals.

Comment: You should check the definition of "maximum". I agree that there is a supremum, and several upper bound, but there is no maximum.

Comment: @Surb Because given a partially ordered set $(U, <)$ (where $<$ is an arbitrary order relationship), and a subset $A$ of $U$, the maximum is a value $M$ such that for all elements $x$ of $A$, $x < M$.

Comment: In the case of the relation $|$, applying it to the set you have defined, there is no maximum. The maximals are $4$, $5$, and $6$, because there are no $x$-elements of the set such as $4|x$, $5|x$, or $6|x$. But none of the maximals is a multiple of all the others, so for all $x$ of the set, $x|4$, $x|5$, nor $x|6$ is not fulfilled.

Comment: It's not **the** value, but **a** value such that .... And this is the definition of an upper-bound, not a maximum.

Comment: "The maximals are 4, 5, and 6" This is worst than what I could even thought ! I really encourage you to see precisely your definition**S**

Comment: In a book that's the definition of maximum. And as maximals, I also use the one in the book, and I think it's the only one there is. Be a partially ordered set $(U, <)$ and $A$ a subset of $U$. A maximal $m$ is an element of $A$ such that no $x$ of $A$ exists that meets the following: $m < x$.